# float casting to nvarchar with constraint max size

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've a table with the name `Article`. It has one column,type's float. I'd want to cast this field to nvarchar and also complete 8 characters. I tried to a a lot of things, but doesn't work. I need your helps.

```
ArticleNo 
11536   ---> 00011536
28508   ---> 00028508
285082  ---> 00285082
28508111 --> 28508111
28508111 --> 28508111
```

Comment: What about decimal points? This is float value after all

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Ms-Sql Server 2008

Comment: SQL Server 2012 adds a FORMAT function. Perhaps you should consider upgrading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(STR(MyFloatColumn, 8, 0), ' ', '0')
FROM
    MyTable;
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 you can use the FORMAT function to achieve full .NET string formatting

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of formatting rather than conversion. SQL Server versions before 2012 are very poor at string formatting. [gbn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443049/134204) solution is probably the easiest to use. It would be better to do string formatting on the client side or on your reporting tool.

SQL Server 2012 adds the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function which acceps a .NET format string. The following statement returns a string formatted using both techniques, although FORMAT is far more powerful:

```
SELECT ArticleNo,
       REPLACE(str(ArticleNo ,8,0),' ','0'),
       FORMAT(ArticleNo,'00000000')
FROM testtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [STR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx). You need something like `SELECT STR([Column_Name],8,0)`

you can also use something like `select cast(cast(cast([Column_Name] as float) as int) as nvarchar(50))`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(ArticleNo))  + CAST(ArticleNo AS NVARCHAR(8))
```

Comment: This will fail with an Arithmetic Overflow error for 28508111